# How to Change Email ID for "Welcome to the SharePoint group: Home Owners for site: Home"

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

In SharePoint 2010 already other person registered their mail id into  "Welcome to the SharePoint group: Home Owners for site: Home" but he is no more my office . so I want register my email id instituted of his mail id .How to change mail id in SharePoint 2010

Comment: You mean to say the From address shown in emails?

Comment: Through my Email ID mail will be send

Comment: Have you tried setting out going email settings from central administration?